# Django : Testing if the page has redirected to the desired url

Tags: python, django, django-testing

In my django app, I have an authentication system. So, If I do not log in and try to access some profile's personal info, I get redirected to a login page.

Now, I need to write a test case for this. The responses from the browsers I get is :

```
GET /myprofile/data/some_id/ HTTP/1.1 302 0
GET /account/login?next=/myprofile/data/some_id/ HTTP/1.1 301 0
GET /account/login?next=/myprofile/data/some_id/ HTTP/1.1 200 6533
```

How do I write my test ? This what I have so far:

```
self.client.login(user="user", password="passwd")
response = self.client.get('/myprofile/data/some_id/')
self.assertEqual(response.status,200)
self.client.logout()
response = self.client.get('/myprofile/data/some_id/')
```

What could possibly come next ?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Django 1.4:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertRedirects

Django 2.0:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects

> `SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, target_status_code=200, msg_prefix='', fetch_redirect_response=True)`
>
> Asserts that the response returned a **status_code** redirect status, redirected to **expected_url** (including any **GET** data), and that the final page was received with **target_status_code**.
>
> If your request used the **follow** argument, the **expected_url** and **target_status_code** will be the url and status code for the final point of the redirect chain.
>
> If **fetch_redirect_response** is **False**, the final page won’t be loaded. Since the test client can’t fetch external URLs, this is particularly useful if **expected_url** isn’t part of your Django app.
>
> Scheme is handled correctly when making comparisons between two URLs. If there isn’t any scheme specified in the location where we are redirected to, the original request’s scheme is used. If present, the scheme in **expected_url** is the one used to make the comparisons to.

Answer (score 60):

You could also follow the redirect with:

```
response = self.client.get('/myprofile/data/some_id/', follow=True)
```

which would mirror the user experience in the browser and make assertions of what you expect to find there, such as:

```
self.assertContains(response, "You must be logged in", status_code=401)
```

Comment: Expecting specific page content in a test is dangerous. Makes it possible that non-programmers (webpage editors) can unknowingly break the tests.

Answer (score 39):

You can check `response['Location']` and see if it matchs with the expected url. Check also that status code is 302.

Comment: Best for when one doesn't care what `target_status_code` will be.

Comment: When doing unit tests on the Views directly (without using the Django client), this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

`response['Location']` doesn't exist in 1.9. Use this instead:

```
response = self.client.get('/myprofile/data/some_id/', follow=True)
last_url, status_code = response.redirect_chain[-1]
print(last_url)
```

Comment: It *is* available if `follow=True` is not provided. Django (any version) does not remove normal response headers like `Location`. When `follow` is `True`, the redirects are followed and naturally the last response has no `Location` header.

Comment: I confirm that Amir is correct (Django 1.11.8), which allows for checking for redirection with ``self.assertRedirects`` (or the ``status_code``) and check the redirection location.

Answer (score 3):

You can use assertRedirects eg:

```
response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects

### If you need to get url which redirected

If `follow` is `True`

You will get url in

```
response.redirect_chain[-1]
```

If `follow` is `False`

```
response.url
```