# Django testing: RequestFactory() follow redirect

Tags: python, django, django-testing

In Django, I have a view, which will redirect to the register page for certain users and I would like to write a test for this.

The standard `request.client.get` used for testing doesn't allow me to specify a user (it just defaults to `anonymous_user`?), so I can't test the behaviour.

With `RequestFactory()` I was able to specify `request.user`. However, it is not following the redirect and the test fails.

```
from .views import my_view
from django.test import RequestFactory()

def test_mytest(self):
    user = create_guest_user()
    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    request = self.factory.get(reverse('my_view'), follow=True)
    request.user = user
    response = my_view(request)
    self.assertContains(response, "page where redirected should contain this")
```

It fails on the last line with this error message:

```
AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 302 (expected 200)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT: As far as I can tell this is not a duplicate as it refers to `RequestFactory()`, which is different from `self.client.get` (where `follow=True` will solve the problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : Testing if the page has redirected to the desired url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951356/django-testing-if-the-page-has-redirected-to-the-desired-url)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. In that case the focus was `SimpleTestCase` over here we are talking the `RequestFactory` class. It is also about following a redirect not `assertRedirect`

Comment: You can't make `RequestFactory()` follow requests. It simply creates a `request` object. If you use `RequestFactory` then you'll need to check the response code, get the redirect location, resolve that location to a view, then call that view. The `client` is designed to take care of all of that for you, so you should use it instead.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair - that helped a lot together with the recommendation below to login the anonymous user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To authenticate the default Django `client`, you can use the [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) method on your `client`:

```
user = create_guest_user()
self.client.force_login(user)
```

> If your site uses Django’s authentication system, you can use the force_login() method to simulate the effect of a user logging into the site. Use this method instead of login() when a test requires a user be logged in and the details of how a user logged in aren’t important.

To follow the redirection (or not) using the test `client`, you must use the `follow` argument, as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get

```
self.client.get(url, follow=True)
```

> If you set follow to True the client will follow any redirects and a redirect_chain attribute will be set in the response object containing tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.

So your full code should look like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_mytest(self):
        user = create_guest_user()
        self.client.force_login(user)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('my_view'), follow=True)
        # Do your assertions on the response here
```

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve the downvote. If the OP wants to follow redirects, then they should use the `client` instead of `RequestFactory()`. This answer shows how to avoid the anonymous user problem when using the client.