# How to test redirection in Django using pytest?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I already know that one can implement a class that inherits from `SimpleTestCase`, and one can test redirection by:

```
SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, target_status_code=200, host=None, msg_prefix='', fetch_redirect_response=True)
```

However, I am wondering what is the way I can check for redirection using pytest:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_redirection_to_home_when_group_does_not_exist(create_social_user):
    """Some docstring defining what the test is checking."""
    c = Client()
    c.login(username='TEST_USERNAME', password='TEST_PASSWORD')
    response = c.get(reverse('pledges:home_group',
                             kwargs={'group_id': 100}),
                     follow=True)
    SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, reverse('pledges:home'))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ```
>   SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, reverse('pledges:home'))
> ```
>
> E       TypeError: assertRedirects() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expected_url'

Is there any way I can use pytest to verify redirection with Django? Or I should go the way using a class that inherits from `SimpleTestCase`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you're going to assert on a redirection you will want to pass `follow=False` not `follow=True` when you call `c.get`.

Comment: @wim, thanks I guess I did it what you are suggesting in conjunction with the answer you provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an instance method, so it will never work like a class method.  You should be able to simply change the line:

```
SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(...)
```

into:

```
SimpleTestCase().assertRedirects(...)
```

i.e. we're creating an instance in order to provide a bound method.

Comment: what do you mean by *bound method*? is it the same as an instance method?

Comment: @wim is there a way to do the "assertRedirect" in pytest only, or is importing from SimpleTestCase the only way to test the url from a redirect?

Comment: @bmeyer71 I would just pass `follow=False` in the `client.get` call and assert on the correct redirection status code (302) and/or the correct redirect url.  Django's `assertRedirects` helper does too much, I avoid to use it really (it also checks that the redirected-to-URL is a 200 - I think that should be a put into a separate test if necessary - e.g., you might have a redirect to offsite resource and you don't want the tests to attempt to GET at that)

Comment: @wim Excellent! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert with pytest so probably is not elegant but you can check for the `Location` header like

```py
test_whatever(self, user):
    client = Client()
    url = reverse('admin:documents_document_add')
    client.force_login(user)

    response = client.post(url, {<something>})

    # if the document is added correctly we redirect
    assert response.status_code == 302
    assert response['Location'] == reverse('admin:documents_document_changelist')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytest_django.asserts.assertRedirects` instead:

```
from pytest_django.asserts import assertRedirects

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_redirection_to_home_when_group_does_not_exist(create_social_user):
    """Some docstring defining what the test is checking."""
    c = Client()
    c.login(username='TEST_USERNAME', password='TEST_PASSWORD')
    response = c.get(reverse('pledges:home_group',
                             kwargs={'group_id': 100}),
                     follow=True)
    assertRedirects(response, reverse('pledges:home'))
```