# Login, Register and Logout test failed AssertionError: 200 != 302 django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to create a test for my login, logout and register views but I keep on getting this error **AssertionError: 200 != 302**. Here are the codes:

**MODEL**
Here is the User model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='user-profile-images/', null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

**VIEWS**
Here is the login and register function view

```
def loginPage(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
             
    return render(request,'registration/login.html', context)

def registerPage(request):
    form = SignupForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect ('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error occured during registration')

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':form})

def logoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

**URLS**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutPage, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),

]
```

**TEST**

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from mydp_app.models import User

class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.login_url = reverse('login')
        self.logout_url = reverse('logout')
        self.register_url = reverse('register')

   def test_register_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('register'), {
            'full_name': 'Test User',
            'username': 'testuser',
            'email': 'testuser@gmail.com',
            'password': 'testpassword',
            'password2': 'testpassword',
        })
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_login_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), {
            'email': 'testuser@gmail.com',
            'password': 'testpassword',
        })
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_logout(self):
        self.client.login(email='testuser@gmail.com', password='testpassword')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('logout'), follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
```

The test expects the status code to be **200** but it is to be redirected. I keep getting this error `self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302) AssertionError: 200 != 302`

Comment: A GET request to the logout will render the `registration/logged_out.html` template, and *not* make a redirect.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a mistake. I would correct it, is should be a post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test that the user was successfully redirected (response code 302) then you can remove `follow=True`:

```
    def test_logged_out_user_was_redirected(self):
        self.client.login(email='testuser@gmail.com', password='testpassword')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('logout'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
```

If you want to ensure that they were redirected to the right place you can set `follow=True`, set the code to 200, and use `assertTemplateUsed`:

```
    def test_logout_redirect_succeeds(self):
        self.client.login(email='testuser@gmail.com', password='testpassword')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('logout'), follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, 'my_app/redirect_page.html')`
```

When you have `follow=True` the response code will be 200 if it succeeds, not 302.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166839/how-to-follow-django-redirect-using-django-pytest) a long time ago and learned that `follow=True` was not possible in pytest. In the process I learned a bit about using the `follow=True` flag.

I am guessing the only test failing right now is `test_logout`. Your code for this is:

```
        response = self.client.post(reverse('logout'), follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or need for clarification and I can clean this up. If I am mistaken let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been able to solve it before now in another way. But your answer was eye-opening and gave me more understanding.