# Django - get URL from TemplateResponse

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that uses the builtin login system.

I'm trying to write a unit test that verifies that the `login` url redirects to `home` if the user is already authenticated.  Meaning, if an already authenticated user tries to visit the `login` url, they get redirected to `home`.

This is a built-in feature of Django's `LoginView`, and I have verified that it is indeed working.  However, I'm not sure how to write a unit test for this.

**Question:** How do I verify that this redirect occurs via unit tests?  `LoginView` returns a `TemplateResponse`, which doesn't have a `url` parameter.

What I have so far is this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

home  = reverse('home')
login = reverse('login')
logout = reverse('logout')
signup = reverse('signup')

USER_CREDS = { some users credentials }

class TestLoginView(TestCase):
    def test_login_redirect(self):
        self.client.post(signup, USER_CREDS)
        self.client.get(logout)
        self.client.post(login, USER_CREDS)
        response = self.client.get(login)
        self.assertRedirects(response, home)
```

**EDIT:**
`SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects` does not work for `TemplateResponse` objects.

`TemplateResponse` objects do not contain a `url` parameter, which is required for `SimpleTestCase.assertRedirect`.

The method raises the following error: `AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'url'`

This is not the same as the linked question, because the response object from a `LoginView` is a `TemplateResponse`, not an `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : Testing if the page has redirected to the desired url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14951356/1165509)

Comment: @marcanuy these are not the same, as explained in the edit.  Thank you for trying to find a suitable answer though.

Answer (score -2):

You can check that the login process redirects to the desired named URL with [assertRedirects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects):

```
SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, target_status_code=200, msg_prefix='', fetch_redirect_response=True)
```

> Asserts that the response returned a status_code redirect status,
>   redirected to expected_url (including any GET data), and that the
>   final page was received with target_status_code.

Then in your test:

```
self.assertRedirects(response, home)
```

## Edit

I've just had a similar problem, few notes:

Instead of performing the login process, you can use `TestCase.force_login` that skips the authentication and verification steps.

```
class TestLoginView(TestCase):
    def test_login_redirect(self):
        self.client.force_login(user)

        # logged user retrieves the login page
        response = self.client.get(login)

        self.assertRedirects(response, home)
```

Response should be a 302 redirect to `home`: `<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/">`

If you are not getting a redirect when doing `response = self.client.get(login)` that means that it is loading the login page, which is what you don't want, so you have to fix that error.

So the problem is not that TemplateResponse objects do not contain a url parameter, it is that your `login` page isn't redirecting a logged in user to the home page.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Are you sure this works?  It's not working for me (saying status=200), and I've verified that the redirect is occurring via the console output (when I manually try to go to that url in the browser).

Comment: @user4343502 I'm sure , I am using it. Capture the response when you do the post, not get, this is where your client logs in.

Comment: I'm testing to see if visiting the url `login` after logging in will redirect me away from the `login` page (I don't want users to visit the `login` page if they're already authenticated).  I think you're referencing the redirect *after* the act of logging in.

Comment: @user4343502 updated answer, it seems it was right after all 8)